# Observe a ManyArray property of an Ember Data model without triggering a load?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've got a `library` model in my application, and it's got a `hasMany` attribute called `books`. Initially, the books for each library aren't loaded. What I'd like to do is detect when they are loaded, and take action:

```
library.addObserver('books.isLoaded', controller, 'controllerMethod');
```

The problem is that the very act of observing `books.isLoaded` itself causes the books to start loading. I'd prefer not to do this, because loading all of a library's books is expensive, and I have lots of libraries whose books I'd like to observe immediately when the application launches.

Is there a way to observe whether or not this property has been loaded without causing it to load?